# How can i show all lines of a text document except a specific line in PHP?

Tags: php

```
$file=fopen("question.txt","r");

while(!feof($file))
{    
  echo "<h3>". fgets($file)."</h3>"."<br />";

  for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++)
  {
    echo fgets($file)."<br />";
  }
}
```

Comment: Except *which* specific line?

Comment: Skip a certain line number or a line containing some string?

Comment: line no-5...............

Comment: @FaymeShahriar: Well, what about `if ($i == 4) continue;` at the top of the loop?

Comment: @jon nope it won't work as there is another echo before loop starts....

Comment: well thanks i have made it work for now.......at the time of fifth line i used fgets(); but didn't print it so it gets hide........:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$lines =`[`file`](http://php.net/file)`("filename.txt");`

and then `$lines[4]` will return you fifth line.

Answer (score 0):

Find and replace the line. Look at str_replace function at http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php :)

Comment: and `str_replace — Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string`

Comment: @DipeshParmar replace by an empty "". ;)

Comment: @JoranDenHouting: That will kill *all* occurrences, not just one line.

Comment: thanks but i wanted to if there is any way to hide @DipeshParmar

Comment: @FaymeShahriar see my answer...now you can wrap that line into hidden div....or anything..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better option in this case... Use the file($path) function to get the lines into an array, then loop through it.

```
$lines = file($path, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$remove = "balblalbllablab";
foreach($lines as $key => $line)
  if(stristr($line, $remove)) unset($lines[$key]);

$data = implode('\n', array_values($lines));

$file = fopen($path);
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```